# How do I get Windows Server 2003 DHCP to hand out my newly-expanded Subnet Mask?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp, subnet

I have a need to have lots of internal SSL sites, so I need lots of internal IPs. With some helpful advice here on this site, I learned I can change my subnet mask to raise the limit of hosts that I have.

I've got my statically-configured servers changed over from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0. But my DHCP-enabled computers all get the subnet mask automatically from my DHCP server. The DHCP server itself is now on 255.255.0.0. But when I renew the lease on a DHCP-enabled client, it still gets the subnet mask 255.255.255.0. I want them all to get 255.255.0.0 automatically.

Note: I would like all of my computers to be able to talk to each other. So I would like them all to have the 255.255.0.0 subnet mask. However, I do not need to increase my DHCP scope (as far as I know). I am fine with it handing out only IPs within 192.168.0.x. I just want those computers that it serves to be able to communicate with the computers who have IPs such as 192.168.60.1.

If I right-click my Scope in DHCP (I have only one DHCP server with one scope), I can see the start and end IP addresses are currently 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.254 respectively (and I have an exclusion range defined elsewhere). However, subnet mask is grayed out. I suppose there is a distinction, though. The subnet mask here likely defines the subnet mask of the range I am defining, which I don't think I need to change. I just want the DHCP server to hand out the newly increased subnet mask to clients that are asking for DHCP service.

So how do I tell my DHCP server "Hey man, we do things differently now. Tell people the subnet mask is 255.255.0.0." I tried saying it out loud but the server was unresponsive.

**Update**: I am going to re-create the scope as suggested. You are probably all correct but I will set an answer after I confirm that it works. Or confirm that it would probably work but I am too stupid to get it to work. :)

**Update 2**: I have a new Windows Server 2008 R2 Server that I am migrating services to. I took this opportunity to install the DHCP role over there and create the new scope on that server instead. When I added the role, the setup wizard was very clear about which IPs were part of the first scope you were creating, and what would get served as the subnet mask. I simply followed the directions. I then authorized the new DHCP service, and De-Authorized the old one. Everything is great now.

Even though I had many DHCP reservations, the whole process only took a half hour. I would have spent as much time fiddling with an import/export process.

Comment: "I tried saying it out loud but the server was unresponsive."  lol

Comment: By the way, the Windows DHCP server is such a huge piece of junk.  This is just one of the many reasons why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the subnet mask of a scope isn't possible.  If you don't have a lot of reservations the simple solution would be to simply create a new scope and disable the old one.

Update, here is an [howto](http://koolbeans.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/howto-import-and-export-dhcp-reservations-in-server-2003/) that describes how to export/import reservations.  I haven't tried this myself though.

Comment: Yikes. I have nearly 100 reservations. This is an opportunity to get rid of a lot of them, though. I made them all before I understood DNS.

Comment: Nuke them 'til they glow.

Comment: In case you are wondering why I have so many reservations. It's because I have a lot of IPv4 devices that need special access rights through the firewall (ISA Server). For example, each of my Sonos nodes needs to be able to stream internet radio, but I don't want my other systems to be able to do that. ISA Server needs IP addresses for access rules, afaik.

Comment: I use them because I want my DNS server to have accurate and non-leftover data in it, yet also have IP addresses supplied by DHCP.  I should probably just use a real DHCP server, since I have disabled all the broken Windows-specific parts of it.

Comment: I have used netsh as described in the article to move entire scopes from one dhcp server to another.  This will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you'll have to define a new scope.  <strike>Might be easier to "[migrate](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325473)" the scope to the same computer and edit the intermediate file.</strike>  Nevermind.  Since they suggested you name that file `dhcpdatabase.txt`, silly me assumed that it was a text file.  Turns out that it's some impenetrable binary blob.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete and recreate your scope.  Have a look at [**this KB**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255999).

Best to just go home if you yell at your servers and they don't listen to you... Bad juju.